# Silverlight Convert PlatformKeyCode to Character Code

Tags: silverlight, textbox, keyboard

**Question:**

Is there a good way in Silverlight to intercept undesirable characters from being entered into a textbox?

**Background:**

I have a textbox which allows a user to enter a filename. I would like to exclude invalid file characters from being entered into the textbox. A few of these characters are:

- '?'
- '\'
- '<'
- '>'

Although the Silverlight TextBox class does not support a KeyPress event, it does have a KeyDown and a KeyUp event that can be used to retrieve character information when a key is entered into the textbox. It exposes these as a member of the **Key** enumeration or it can return an int for the **PlatformKeyCode**.

Of course the range of keys is larger/different from the range of characters - "F keys" are an example of this. However the presence of something like a KeyPress event in Windows Forms is indicative of the usefulness of being able to extract specific character information.

To do a proof of concept that things could work I hardcoded the PlatformKeyCode values for the undesired characters for my platform into the event handler and everything worked... but *of course* this is just my platform. I need to make sure this implementation is platform agnostic. Here is the code to demonstrate how I would like it to work:

```
    private void theText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] illegals = { 191, 188, 190, 220, 186, 222, 191, 56, 186};
        if (illegals.Any(i => i == e.PlatformKeyCode)) e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for making it this complicated? It would be much easier to just strip out the undesired characters with a regular expression whenever the text changes (The TextChanged event on the TextBox).

Comment: Henrik's solution sounds much easier.  Another idea is to declare a property for the text in the textbox, and use validation on the property to indicate to the user which characters are not allowed.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I tried to attribute the solution to you in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both responses (in comments) from *Henrik* and *Johannes* contain the best answer for the scenario. Rather than thinking like a Windows Forms programmer and capturing the specific key event, the canonical approach in Silverlight is to use the TextChanged event to remove undesirable characters from a TextBox. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977202/silverlight-numeric-textbox) on allowing only numeric input to a TextBox is what prompted the solution that was used.

The following code samples the approach I took after reading the comments and it works quite well to remove characters inappropriate for entry:

```
    private void fileNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string illegalChars = @"?<>:""\/*|";
        fileNameTextBox.Text = String.Join("", fileNameTextBox.Text.Split(illegalChars.ToCharArray()));
        fileNameTextBox.SelectionStart = fileNameTextBox.Text.Length;
    }
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that you could remove the characters using the Split method. That's "t3rse"!!

Comment: yeah but pay attention in doing that because as string are internalized you'll probably end up in filling the memory with tiny useless pieces of strings if you type a lot in this textbox, but maybe it is fine for your use case

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

public class FilterTextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public readonly static DependencyProperty AllowAlphaCharactersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllowAlphaCharacters", typeof(bool), typeof(FilterTextBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool AllowAlphaCharacters
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowAlphaCharactersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowAlphaCharactersProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty AllowNumericCharactersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllowNumericCharacters", typeof(bool), typeof(FilterTextBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool AllowNumericCharacters
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowNumericCharactersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowNumericCharactersProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty AllowSpecialCharactersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AllowSpecialCharacters", typeof(bool), typeof(FilterTextBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool AllowSpecialCharacters
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowSpecialCharactersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowSpecialCharactersProperty, value); }
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty DoNotFilterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DoNotFilter", typeof(string), typeof(FilterTextBoxBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string DoNotFilter
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DoNotFilterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DoNotFilterProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (AssociatedObject == null) { return; }

        FilterAssociatedObject();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        if (AssociatedObject == null) { return; }

        FilterAssociatedObject();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) { FilterAssociatedObject(); }
    private void FilterAssociatedObject()
    {
        int cursorLocation = AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;

        for (int i = AssociatedObject.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            char c = AssociatedObject.Text[i];
            if (ValidChar(c)) { continue; }

            AssociatedObject.Text = AssociatedObject.Text.Remove(i, 1);
            cursorLocation--;
        }

        AssociatedObject.SelectionStart = Math.Min(AssociatedObject.Text.Length, Math.Max(0, cursorLocation));
    }

    private bool ValidChar(char c)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DoNotFilter) && DoNotFilter.Contains(c)) { return true; }
        if (!AllowAlphaCharacters && char.IsLetter(c)) { return false; }
        if (!AllowNumericCharacters && char.IsNumber(c)) { return false; }
        if (!AllowSpecialCharacters && Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), @"[\W|_]")) { return false; }

        return true;
    }
}
```