# How to change entered TextBox text in binded property setter?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Using MVVM in Silverlight, on my View I have:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Temperature,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

MyViewModel has:

```
public MyModel Model {get{...}set{...}}//In my code I do have the property changed events for this
public string Temperature
{
    get
    {
        return Model.Temperature.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        double test;
        if(double.TryParse(value, out test))
        {
            Model.Temperature = test;
        }
        else
        {
            Model.Temperature = 0D;
        }
    }
}

void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Temperature":
            OnPropertyChanged("Temperature");
            break;
    }
}
```

MyModel has:

```
private double _temperature;
public double Temperature
{
    get
    {
        return _temperature;
    }
    set
    {
        _temperature = value; OnPropertyChanged("Temperature");
    }
}
```

If the user enters something that would not parse to a double, the Model.Temperature property gets set to 0, and I would like the TextBox to also change to 0. I thought the OnPropertyChanged events would take care of that. Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, OnPropertyChanged gets called in the Model, the ViewModel catches it and calls it for the View Model too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
This is caused because the Text will not call the get during the call to set. This could cause a bad infinite loop. You have a few choices.

Delay firing property changed for the error condition:

```
public string Temperature
{
    get { return Model.Temperature.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        double test;
        if (double.TryParse(value, out test))
        {
            Model.Temperature = test;
        }
        else
        {
            Model.Temperature = 0D;
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => OnPropertyChanged("Temperature"));
        }
    }
}
```

Use a [NumericTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977202/silverlight-numeric-textbox)

Implement [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on your ViewModel and set ValidatesOnDataErrors on your TextBox to true

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Temperature, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

OLD:
Make sure that your binding allow for [two way binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#direction_of_the_data_flow). Without it, you cannot set the TextProperty of the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: I already have this, as included in my code samples in the post.

Comment: sorry, did not see that part. Updated my answer

Comment: The delay and IDataErrorInfo both look very promising, I looked at Numeric textboxes of various kinds but was not completely sold. If it comes down to it, I guess I'll try that as a last resort.

Comment: limiting user input to only numbers is a very common thing and [most] users understand that they cannot input 'p' for their age

Comment: hmm, that is a good point. I suppose I might be over complicating this. I still lean towards preventing as many unexpected events as possible.

Comment: Anyway, processing the entered value and changing it seems to be something not so strange isn't it?