# XamlParseException Failed to assign to property. Binding not working with attached property

Tags: xaml, exception, binding, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I want to create custom text box with attached property for Windows Store app. I am following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977202/silverlight-numeric-textbox). Now it uses hard coded value as property value but I want to set value using binding, but it's not working. I tried to search a lot but didn't helped me any solution.

The exception details is like this

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in CustomTextBox.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'CustomTextBox.Input.Type'.

MainPage.xaml

```
<!-- local:Input.Type="Email" works -->
<!-- local:Input.Type="{Binding SelectedTextboxInputType}" not working -->

<TextBox x:Name="txt" local:Input.Type="{Binding SelectedTextboxInputType}" Height="30" Width="1000" />

<ComboBox x:Name="cmb"  ItemsSource="{Binding TextboxInputTypeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTextboxInputType}" Height="30" Width="200" 
          Margin="451,211,715,527" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Input.cs

```
//InputType is enum
public static InputType GetType(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (InputType)obj.GetValue(TypeProperty);
}

public static void SetType(DependencyObject obj, InputType value)
{
    obj.SetValue(TypeProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Type", typeof(InputType), typeof(TextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(InputType), OnTypeChanged));

private static void OnTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue is InputType)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)d;
        var Type = (InputType)e.NewValue;
        if (Type == InputType.Email || Type == InputType.URL)
        {
            textBox.LostFocus += OnLostFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        TextboxInputTypeList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(InputType)).Cast<InputType>();
    }

    private InputType _SelectedTextboxInputType = InputType.Currency;
    public InputType SelectedTextboxInputType
    {
        get { return _SelectedTextboxInputType; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._SelectedTextboxInputType, value); }
    }

    private IEnumerable<InputType> _TextboxInputTypeList;
    public IEnumerable<InputType> TextboxInputTypeList
    {
        get { return _TextboxInputTypeList; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._TextboxInputTypeList, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Incorrect

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Type", typeof(InputType), typeof(TextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(InputType), OnTypeChanged));
```

Correct

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Type", typeof(InputType), typeof(Input), new PropertyMetadata(default(InputType), OnTypeChanged));
```

Comment: Good for you! Solution at last!

Answer (score 11):

This is a pretty common mistake. The problem is, binding targets cannot be CLR properties in XAML. It's just the rules. A binding source can be a CLR property, just fine. The targets simply must be dependency properties.

We all get the error! :)

[image]

I describe the whole thing here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2013/07/02/walkthrough-two-way-binding-inside-a-xaml-user-control.aspx

Best of luck.

Comment: Above solution didn't work for me because `Type` property is already dependency property. Moreover I can't write `(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` in the constructor of class `Input` because it's static class & it's not inheriting `UserControl` class. Jerry, I request you to perform a demo of what I asked in the question. Thanks :)

Comment: What you ask for and what I have time for aren't aligned right now. I'm sorry. In the meantime, this is your best sample: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.cs

Comment: Hey Jerry, I tried a lot but not getting solution :( Better you post the exact solution, I need to reach deadline.

Comment: Did you look here? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779344/vs2012-xaml-designer-fails-to-resolve-binding-to-attached-property-in-a-style and http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update

Comment: I checked it but it's not related to my problem. I updated my question by adding `Input.cs`. I also followed your latest [blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/08/windows-8-xaml-manipulation-using.html) for attached property, but I can't succeed.

Comment: Finally got the solution, it was too shorter mistake in declaration of attached property.