# Bind property to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I am having the same issue as in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971195/xamlparseexception-failed-to-assign-to-property-binding-not-working-with-attach).

I've also read this [article](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html) but I can't find the reason why I've get this Exception:

[image]

I am calling a UserControl in which another UserControl should be called.

Inside the first UserControl I'll want to do the following

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TwitterUniversalHubTest1.UCGlobalTweet"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TwitterUniversalHubTest1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="150"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid Height="Auto">
    <Border Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="10 0 0 5" CornerRadius="2 2 15 2">
        <Grid Width="380">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Tag="{Binding UserID}" Grid.Row="0" Name="ProfileInfo" Tapped="Profile_Tapped" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 15 15 0">
                <Grid Width="360" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="45" Width="45" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 5 0 0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TwitterHandle}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/ActionIcons/Twitter_logo_blue_32.png" Width="32" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0" Height="Auto">

                <StackPanel Name="TwContent" Tag="{Binding TweetID}" Margin="15 0 15 0" Tapped="Content_Tapped">

                    <local:ComplexTextPresenter x:Name="ComplexTextPresenterElement" Input="{Binding Content}" DataContext="{Binding Content}"/>
                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ContentImages}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding }" MaxWidth="350" Margin="0 0 0 5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray" Text="{Binding DateSend}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="ActionButtons">
                    <Grid Tag="{Binding TweetID}" Width="380" Height="25" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource replyActionButton}" Tapped="Reply_Tapped"></Button>

                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource retweetActionButton}" Tapped="Retweet_Tapped"></ToggleButton>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RetweetCount}" Foreground="DarkGray"/>

                        <ToggleButton x:Name="FavButton" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource likeActionButton}" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding LikeState}"  
                                          Tapped="Favourite_Tapped"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LikeCount}" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The Content property in `Input="{Binding Content}"` is a string.

The problem occurs with the Input property binding. The binding in the ItemsControl works fine. As the exceptions describes the binding is in Line:43 Position: 90.

The code-behind for the `ComplexTextPresenterElement` looks like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Input", typeof(string), typeof(UCGlobalTweet), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), InputPropertyChangedCallback));

private static void InputPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    var ctrl = dependencyObject as ComplexTextPresenter;
    if (ctrl == null)
        return;
    ctrl.Init();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InputCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(UCGlobalTweet), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<object>)));
public static readonly DependencyProperty OnHyperlinkCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OnHyperlinkCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UCGlobalTweet), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

private IEnumerable<object> GetParsedInput()
{
    List<BaseInputPart> inputParts = new List<BaseInputPart>();
    var strings = Input.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        if (s.IsHyperlink())
        {
            inputParts.Add(new HyperLinkPart { Content = s });
        }
        else
        {
            inputParts.Add(new LiteralPart { Content = s });
        }
    }
    return inputParts.OfType<object>().ToList();
}

public string Input
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(InputProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
}

public ObservableCollection<object> InputCollection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(InputCollectionProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(InputCollectionProperty, value); }
}

public ICommand OnHyperlinkCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OnHyperlinkCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OnHyperlinkCommandProperty, value); }
}

private void Init()
{
    InputCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(GetParsedInput());
}

public ComplexTextPresenter()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}


public abstract class BaseInputPart
{
    public abstract string Content { get; set; }
}

public class HyperLinkPart : BaseInputPart
{
    public override string Content { get; set; }
}

public class LiteralPart : BaseInputPart
{
    public override string Content { get; set; }
}
```

//UPDATE: This is the UCGlobalTweet.xaml.cs

```
    public sealed partial class UCGlobalTweet : UserControl
{
    private readonly NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private readonly ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
    private readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");

    //passingparameter
    public string MyContentProperty { get; set; }

    public UCGlobalTweet()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {

        ComplexTextPresenterElement.Input = "This is where the Content string has to be....";
        ComplexTextPresenterElement.OnHyperlinkCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute);
    }

    private void Execute(object o)
    {
        //put here the code that can open browser 
    }

    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    // Tap user specific content
    private void Profile_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I've clicked on information from Profile --> UserInfoPage");
        List<object> passingParameters = new List<object>();

        StackPanel st = (StackPanel)sender;
        string userIDList = (string)st.Tag;

        //provisional Data transfer
        // get UserObject out of SearchResult, therefore I have to put the user content as a global variable to access it here, but this will require a lot of space probably...
        // So for now I recall the UserObject again.

        var usersResponse =
               (from user in TweetContent.Connection.User
                where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                      user.UserIdList == userIDList
                //user.ScreenNameList == "JoeMayo,Linq2Tweeter"
                select user).ToList();

        User curUser = usersResponse.FirstOrDefault();
        passingParameters.Add(curUser);

        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(UserInfoPage), passingParameters);
    }

    // Tap tweet specific content
    private void Content_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I've clicked the Tweet content --> Going to TweetInfoPage");
        List<object> passingParameters = new List<object>();

        StackPanel ContentTapped = (StackPanel)sender;
        ulong tag = (ulong)ContentTapped.Tag;
        var test = TweetContent.FulltweetList;
        var tweet = test.FirstOrDefault(tw => tw.TweetID == tag);

        passingParameters.Add(tweet);


        (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(TweetInfoPage), passingParameters);

    }

    //Action Buttons
    private void Reply_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Reply Button Tapped");
        var test = (Button)sender;

        e.Handled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("New State for Reply: " + test.IsPressed);
    }

    private void Retweet_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Retweet Button Tapped");
        //var test = (Button)sender;

        //e.Handled = true;
        //Debug.WriteLine("New State for Retweet: " + test.IsPressed);
    }

    private async void Favourite_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Favourite Button Tapped");
            ToggleButton tBtn = (ToggleButton)sender;
            Grid pGrid = (Grid)tBtn.Parent;
            var curTweet = TweetContent.FulltweetList.Where(tw => tw.TweetID.Equals(pGrid.Tag));

            if (tBtn.IsChecked == false)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Status should be Checked: " + tBtn.IsChecked);
                await TweetContent.Connection.DestroyFavoriteAsync((ulong)pGrid.Tag);
                curTweet.First().LikeCount--;
            }

            if (tBtn.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Status should be UnChecked: " + tBtn.IsChecked);
                await TweetContent.Connection.CreateFavoriteAsync((ulong)pGrid.Tag);
                curTweet.First().LikeCount++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error while updating Favourite State: Message: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void RealLink_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hyperlink = sender as Hyperlink;
        if (hyperlink == null) return;
        //Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }

}
```

And here comes the ComplexTextPresenter.xaml - the second UserControl which I was speaking of

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TwitterUniversalHubTest1.ComplexTextPresenter"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ts="using:TwitterUniversalHubTest1"
xmlns:panel="using:Gregstoll"  
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" x:Name="This">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HyperlinkDataTemplateKey">
            <HyperlinkButton Padding="0" Margin="0" FontSize="12" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Command="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=OnHyperlinkCommand}" Content="{Binding Path=Content}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LiteralDataTemplateKey">
            <TextBlock Padding="0" Margin="0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Content}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ts:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelectorKey"
                              LiteralDataTemplate ="{StaticResource LiteralDataTemplateKey}"
                              HyperlinkDataTemplate="{StaticResource HyperlinkDataTemplateKey}"/>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!--<Rectangle Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>-->
    <ListBox Margin="-5 0 0 15" Foreground="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=InputCollection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelectorKey}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <panel:UniversalWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Cheers,
Ulpin

Comment: What is the `DataContext` of the binding?

Comment: I'm not putting a value in the `DataContext`

Comment: But there must be some value in the `DataContext` in order to make the binding work, or you need to point out the `Source` or the `ElementName` explicitly instead.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Ok. This does't work... and doesn't seem to make sense:
<local:ComplexTextPresenter x:Name="ComplexTextPresenterElement" Input="{Binding Content}" DataContext="{Binding Content}"/>
But what should I put into the DataContext?

Comment: You shouldn't put anything there, I just want to know what is the `DataContext`. Can you share the complete XAML code?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your properties you should pass the type of the class, which contains the properties, but you're passing `typeof(UCGlobalTweet)` instead. You should do it like this:

```
class ComplexTextPresenterElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Input", typeof(string), typeof(ComplexTextPresenterElement), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), InputPropertyChangedCallback));    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ComplexTextPresenterElement), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<object>)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OnHyperlinkCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OnHyperlinkCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ComplexTextPresenterElement), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));
}
```

Comment: Thank You. This seems to be working. I've played with excatly these three lines of code for hours and couldn't figure it out. But still the binding isn't correct. 
I am not getting an error anymore but the Content isn't shown instead there is `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid`... Do you have an idea what this is about?

Comment: In the code-behind of the UCGlobalTweet userControl I'm doing the calculations to prepare the Content string from the binding. I think there is something wrong at the Init() function because the ComplexTextPresenterElement instance is not initialized at this point, thats why I tried something with the var test = [...]

Comment: @Ulpin Sorry, I can't help you without the complete source code.

Comment: It's working now. With the correct DependencyProperty in this answer and the Binding `Input=""{Binding Content}`.
Thank you very much!!! Great!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `DataContext`, `ElementName` nor `Source` in your bindings. There are several approaches to make the code work, I will give you the easiest ones, you can pick any of these.

1) Set the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. That is a bad approach though, as you may overwrite the existing `DataContext` or have it overwritten from the external code.

2) Name your `UserControl` and bind to it using `ElementName`.

```
Input="{Binding Content, ElementName=userControl}"
```

3) Use `{x:Bind}`:

```
Input="{x:Bind Content}"
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. 
But why are the other bindings working in the UserControl? What is the difference using a binding to another UserControl?

Comment: @Ulpin Every control in `DataTemplate` have `DataContext` set to the current item implicitly. Plus, your `UserControl` can have `DataContext` set from the external code (as it is a `UserControl`).

Comment: @Ulpin Consider using `{x:Bind}`, it's the best solution for you. I've updated the answer, take a look at it.

Comment: I'll tried all three options - no success. in 1) and 2) I've got the same error as described and in 3) I am not allowed to use x:bind in a WindowsPhoneproject

Comment: @Ulpin The third approach will work only in UWP apps. Did you remove the `DataContext` from `<local:ComplexTextPresenter/>`?

Comment: Yes, Sure. I reversed all changes before trying the next one

Comment: @Ulpin And you named your `UserControl`?

Comment: Yes. I did: x:Name="UserControl"  at the top of the xaml and tried binding with: <local:ComplexTextPresenter x:Name="ComplexTextPresenterElement" Input="{Binding Content, ElementName=UserControl}">

Comment: @Ulpin The code-behind you posted belongs to `ComplexTextPresenterElement` or `UCGlobalTweet`? I thought it belongs to `UCGlobalTweet` cause you set it as the parent class, but I've just noticed that you state it belongs to `ComplexTextPresenterElement`. I will write another answer below.